# Is there R code to remove rows with continuous blanks only

Tags: r, filtering

I have a data frame in which the first column is email addresses and the rest of the columns are statements that the person agreed with. I want to filter out only the rows in which the person agreed with nothing. If they agree with one thing they stay in (so below only doug's row would be removed.

```
Email         C1    C2    C3
q@gmail.com   agree       agree
bob@gmail.com       agree
doug@gmail.com]
```

I tried this in excel without luck. I have not seen R code that can fix it.

Answer (score 0):

One base `R` solution using `rowSums()` to count non blank cells per row

```
df <- df[rowSums(df != "") > 1, ]

> df
          Email    C1    C2    C3
1   q@gmail.com agree       agree
2 bob@gmail.com       agree
```